# Read rows from a data frame which lie within a certain date range

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to learn data manipulation with Python and here is the challenge I am stuck with. I am reading data from a CSV file into my data frame which has columns as shown below.

```
         Item    Qty    InvoiceDate  CalcStartDate  CalcEndDate
         abc     10      04-10-2022   04-20-2022     12-12-2022
         aby     10      04-17-2022   04-20-2022     12-12-2022
         abd     11      12-15-2022   04-20-2022     12-12-2022
         xyz     9       05-21-2022   01-01-2022     06-30-2022
         xyp     13      07-01-2023   01-01-2022     06-30-2022
         mno     10      07-20-2023   01-01-2022     06-30-2022
```

From my data-frame I want to extract rows with items: aby, abd, xyp and xyz since for these four rows the respective "InvoiceDate" lies between the respective ("CalcStartDate" - 7 days) and ("CalcEndDate" + 7 days). I tried the following which gives me rows between the "CalcStartDate" and "CalcEndDate" but when I try to add or subtract the 7 days, it throws error.

```
     df[(df["InvoiceDate"] >= df["CalcStartDate") & (df["InvoiceDate"] <= df["CalcEndDate"])]
```

I looked at "Timedelta" but since I am dealing with large number of records/data, I am not quite sure that would be the best approach to address my need.

Would be much grateful for any advice/directions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I hope you have made sure the data in the columns are in datetime format. You can check this by using `df.info()` and it should look like this...

```
>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------         --------------  -----         
 0   Item           6 non-null      object        
 1   Qty            6 non-null      int64         
 2   InvoiceDate    6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 3   CalcStartDate  6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 4   CalcEndDate    6 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](3), int64(1), object(1)
```

As you want to compare the difference in days, you can subtract the columns and then check the number of days using `.dt.days` and finally compare it to 7... The result for your data above would look like this. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
df[((df["CalcStartDate"] - df["InvoiceDate"]).dt.days <= 7) 
   & ((df["InvoiceDate"] - df["CalcEndDate"]).dt.days <= 7)]
```

**Output**

```
Item    Qty InvoiceDate CalcStartDate   CalcEndDate
1   aby 10  2022-04-17  2022-04-20  2022-12-12
2   abd 11  2022-12-15  2022-04-20  2022-12-12
3   xyz 9   2022-05-21  2022-01-01  2022-06-30
4   xyp 13  2022-07-01  2022-01-01  2022-06-30
```

Comment: Thanks @Redox! Had to be mindful of the data type there.